# Inserting arrays into parquet using spark sql query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to add complex data types to a parquet file using the SQL query option.

I've had partial success using the following code:

```py
self._operationHandleRdd = spark_context_.sql(u"INSERT OVERWRITE 
    TABLE _df_Dns VALUES 
      array(struct(struct(35,'ww'),5,struct(47,'BGN')),
                   struct(struct(70,'w'),1,struct(82,'w')),
                   struct(struct(86,'AA'),1,struct(97,'ClU'))
      )")

spark_context_.sql("select * from _df_Dns").collect()

[Row(dns_rsp_resource_record_items=[Row(dns_rsp_rr_name=Row(seqno=86, value=u'AA'),
dns_rsp_rr_type=1, dns_rsp_rr_value=Row(seqno=97, value=u'ClU')),
Row(dns_rsp_rr_name=Row(seqno=86, value=u'AA'), dns_rsp_rr_type=1,
dns_rsp_rr_value=Row(seqno=97, value=u'ClU')),
Row(dns_rsp_rr_name=Row(seqno=86, value=u'AA'), dns_rsp_rr_type=1,
dns_rsp_rr_value=Row(seqno=97, value=u'ClU'))])]
```

So, this returns an array with 3 items but the last item appears thrice.

Did anyone encounter such issues and found a way around just by using Spark SQL and not Python?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(dns_rsp_resource_record_items=[Row(
        dns_rsp_rr_name=Row(
            seqno=35, value=u'ww'),
        dns_rsp_rr_type=5, 
        dns_rsp_rr_value=Row(seqno=47, value=u'BGN')),
    Row(
        dns_rsp_rr_name=Row(
            seqno=70, value=u'w'), 
        dns_rsp_rr_type=1,
        dns_rsp_rr_value=Row(
            seqno=82, value=u'w')),
    Row(
        dns_rsp_rr_name=Row(
            seqno=86, value=u'AA'), 
        dns_rsp_rr_type=1,
        dns_rsp_rr_value=Row(
            seqno=97, 
            value=u'ClU'))])])
df.write.saveAsTable("_df_Dns")
```

Overwriting and inserting new lines work fine with your code (appart from the extra parenthesis):

```py
spark.sql(u"INSERT OVERWRITE \
    TABLE _df_Dns VALUES \
      array(struct(struct(35,'ww'),5,struct(47,'BGN')), \
                   struct(struct(70,'w'),1,struct(82,'w')), \
                   struct(struct(86,'AA'),1,struct(97,'ClU')) \
      )")
spark.sql("select * from _df_Dns").show(truncate=False)

    +---------------------------------------------------------------+
    |dns_rsp_resource_record_items                                  |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[[[35,ww],5,[47,BGN]], [[70,w],1,[82,w]], [[86,AA],1,[97,ClU]]]|
    +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The only possible reason I see for the weird outcome you get is that your initial table had a compatible but different schema.

```py
df.printSchema()

    root
     |-- dns_rsp_resource_record_items: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- dns_rsp_rr_name: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- seqno: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- dns_rsp_rr_type: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- dns_rsp_rr_value: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- seqno: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```